# Flutter how to make bottomsheet which stay always on top of every page

Tags: flutter, dart

**bottomsheet(not bottombar) which stay alway on top of entire app.if open an page it always stay on top**

```
WidgetsApp(
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  color: Colors.pink,
  builder: (context, child) => Stack(
    children: [
      GetMaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        color: Colors.pink,
        home: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
          body: Center(
            child: TextButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Text(
                'data',
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
       //bottomsheet
      Positioned(
        bottom: 0,
        left: 0,
        right: 0,
        child: PlayerSheet(),
      )
    ],
  ),
);
```

> something like above

Comment: use stack widget

Comment: Create your page wrapper, make its content as `Stack`, provide one child(bottom sheet) with `Positioned` and make the rest of the content as a child parameter which you are passing when creating your pages e.g. `PageWrapper(child: Container())` . So each of your pages should be wrapped by `PageWrapper`. If you need more help, let me know I can write an example for you.

Comment: yes i need more help

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/sticky_footer_scrollview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create something like this as your page wrapper:

```
class StickyPageWrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;
  const StickyPageWrapper({Key key, this.child}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    return Stack(
      fit: StackFit.expand,
      children: [
        child,
        Positioned(
          left: 0,
          bottom: 0,
          child: Hero(
            tag: 'bottom_sheet',
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.orange,
              height: size.height / 4,
              width: size.width,
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Then use it like this for one page:

```
class Page1 extends StatelessWidget {
  const Page1({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: StickyPageWrapper(
          child: Container(
        color: Colors.white38,
        child: Center(
            child: ElevatedButton(
          child: Text('Go to page 2'),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context)
                .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Page2()));
          },
        )),
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

Then for the other page:

```
class Page2 extends StatelessWidget {
  const Page2({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: StickyPageWrapper(
          child: Container(
        color: Colors.white38,
        child: Center(
            child: ElevatedButton(
          child: Text('Go back to page 1'),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
          },
        )),
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

And so on, so you wrap your every page.
I added a Hero animation to your `BottomSheet` when navigating between pages: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/animations/hero-animations so that it looks bit nicer and more natural.

Hope this helps, let me know if I can help further.

Note: This is actually not a `BottomSheet` widget if that was your idea, because typically that one is created implicitly by `ScaffoldState.showBottomSheet`, for persistent bottom sheets, or by `showModalBottomSheet`, for modal bottom sheets.

Comment: thanks zpouip for your effort yor answer helps me 

Comment: No problems, I am glad it worked. Would you mind marking the answer as the correct one in case someone else also needs it? Thanks.

Comment: thanks @zpouip for the idea. This is not a bottomsheet but we can create a similar behaviour from here.